# Behat SymfonyExtension Configuration for specific Kernel

Tags: symfony, behat

I have a specific Kernel for my application `SpecificKernel.php` under the `app/SpecificKernel.php`, I need to specify in my `behat.yml` to use this Kernel instead of the default one.

```
default:
    suites:
        first:
            type: symfony_bundle
            bundle: MyBundle
            mink_session: selenium2
            contexts:
                - MyBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext

            # Should be placed somewhere in this file, but I do not know where
            #symfony2_extension:
                #kernel:
                    #path: app/SpecificKernel.php
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url:  http://www.example.local
            sessions:
                default:
                    symfony2: ~
                selenium2:
                    selenium2: ~
```

From the source code of `SymfonyExtension` i found that it should be set in symfony2_extension->kernel->path, but the problem is that I do not know where to put this configuration, I tried multiple ways and each time the default error `Class AppKernel does not exist` has arrived.

Can you please suggest where to put the `symfony2_extension configurations` in the behat.yml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after 2 hours of work eventually I managed to do it, the problem was that you should specify not only the `path` but the `class` also. Finally I got something like this:

```
default:
    suites:
        reglements:
            type: symfony_bundle
            bundle: MyBundle
            mink_session: selenium2
            contexts:
                - MyBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
                path: app/SpecificKernel.php
                class: SpecificKernel
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url:  http://www.example.local
            sessions:
                default:
                    symfony2: ~
                selenium2:
                    selenium2: ~
```